# Unexpected string concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fix my code using eslint and its throwing an error saying:

```
cName: "" + ANR + "",
```

> Unexpected string concatenation

```
const ANR = 'Animal Friend,ANR,ANP,$30';

        const specialityPlates = [{
      cName: 'Environmental / Wildlife',
      oSubMenu: [{
        cName: "" + ANR + "",
        cReturn: "" + ANR + "|27.00"
      },
      {
```

What is wrong with the concatenation in this string?

Comment: As long as `ANR` has no `'` in it everything should be fine.

Comment: If ANR is already a string just do `cName:  ANR,`

Comment: perhaps update your answer with that useful information rather than just in comment . . .

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Use template literals. Try this `${ANR}`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

ie.

```
const ANR = 'Animal Friend,ANR,ANP,$30'
const specialityPlates = [
  {
    cName: 'Environmental / Wildlife',
    oSubMenu: [{
      cName: `${ANR}`, // "Animal Friend,ANR,ANP,$30"
      cReturn: `${ANR}|27.00` // "Animal Friend,ANR,ANP,$30|27.00"
    }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 56):

**To be clear**: *there is nothing wrong with your syntax<sup>1</sup>*.

**It is not JavaScript throwing that error**, it is your linter settings which have the `no-useless-concat` rule set to throw an error when it detects classic string concatenation:

```
// classic string concatenation
'a' + 'b' + 'c';
```

but a linter error is not always the same as a JavaScript error, so just to be clear, your use of string concatenation is not incorrect, and would not throw a JavaScript error if you tried to run that code in the browser, or Node, etc. You are only seeing an error because your linter rules have been configured to prefer template strings over string concatenation.

The `no-useless-concat` rule assumes you are in an environment where ES6 template literals are supported, and using the `no-useless-concat` rule helps enforce the preference for template literals over string concatenation. So your linter found an example of string concatenation, and threw an error to remind you that template literals should be used instead (keep in mind that your linter is configurable, so you have this setting turned on by choice, or the project you are working on is trying to enforce a specific coding style).

So with the `no-useless-concat` rule,

```
// This will throw an error
"" + ANR + "|27.00";

// Use template literals instead
`${ANR}|27.00`;
```

If you want to learn more about the rule (how to disable it, change the error setting, disable it all together, etc), then here is the documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-concat

---

<sup>1</sup> While there is nothing wrong with your syntax *per se*, its not necessary to pad empty strings for string concatenation if you already know that the value you are printing is a string. Doing `ANR + 'something'` is enough, no need for `'' + ANR + 'something' + ''`. The only time you would ever need to pad empty strings is if you were trying to ensure that the value you were printing was [cast to a string](http://2ality.com/2012/03/converting-to-string.html) before the concatenation happened, but typically, you would want to know the datatype of the variable you are printing before printing it.

Comment: I don't know the real reason, but in my case I had to disable the "prefer-template" rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template

Comment: @FernandoTholl if disabling the rule worked for you, it just means that your linter will no longer care what you do with string concatenation or template strings, allowing you to choose whatever feature you want. I find the only reason to have the rule enabled is for better readability (template strings are easier for humans to read), so the idea is _"if templates are available in your environment, we prefer that you use them"_

Comment: The rule can be disabled by placing this comment just above the statement where the concatenation occurs: `// eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-concat`

Answer (score 13):

Here is a different example using eslint error: Unexpected string concatenation | prefer-template:

**(YES)**

```
const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
```

vs

**(NO)**

```
const value = '; ' + document.cookie;
const parts = value.split('; ' + name + '=');
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this comment to the line "// eslint-disable-line prefer-template"

Linting is completely superficial and unless there is a real need to use a template, the author (you) should not be burdened by superficial changes.